# Where and how does Stack Overflow store its data?

Tags: discussion, database, stack-overflow

Where does Stack Overflow store its data - MySql, CouchDB? And how does the "related questions", shown at every page, work?

Basically I want to know the ontology used here to store the data so that the data is easily accessible, and on what basis it suggests the related questions - using tags?

Comment: How data is organized- one refers to other                          How they come to know that this question is related to these questions?

Comment: This is *still* not the right place to ask this question!